# unity дрожание объекта при движение

Tags: c#, unity3d, controller

Есть Объект, главный персонаж и когда в rigidbody вкл гравитация, то при перемещении персонажа он подергивается.
Видео - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WfTmejZ3guE2EYkujfpH-pJw936qClLD

Код управления.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody myBody;
    public float moveForce = 10f;

    private VariableJoystick joystick;

    private PlayerAnimation anim;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        joystick = GameObject.FindWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<VariableJoystick>(); 
        anim = GetComponent<PlayerAnimation>();       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        myBody.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * moveForce, myBody.velocity.y, joystick.Vertical * moveForce);

        if(joystick.Horizontal != 0f || joystick.Vertical != 0f)
        {
            anim.Run(true);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(myBody.velocity);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.Run(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Всю работу с физикой стоит выносить в FixedUpdate() вместо Update() - т.к. Update() это в первую очередь синхронизация с визуальным рендером, в то время как FixedUpdate() это синхронизация с физ движком

Comment: Спасибо, это нужно сделать void FixedUpdate после void Update ?

Comment: Сделал, но к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Сдается мне, что тут у вас проблема с вращением объекта. Если не включено - включите галочку freezeRotation у Rigidbody и посмотрите, поменяется ли картина

Comment: Здравствуйте!
В rigidbody  freezeRotation по всем осям стоят галочки

Answer (score 0):

Настроил NavMesh (сделал bake поверхности) и перестало дёргаться.

Comment: Было бы неплохо указать, что именно настроили в NavMesh.

Comment: сделал bake поверхности, и подергивания исчезли

Comment: “Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.”